# Find the probability distribution of the distance, of a random point in a unit square, from some diagonal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I already did some work on this, and would like to know, if I am not wrong.

Basically I have a unit square (sides $1\times1$). In that square I pick a point, in a random way. Next I will define random variable $X$, whose value is defined as "the minimal distance of the randomly picked point, from some diagonal".

I measured  the distance between the point and the diagonal, as the length of a line between the two, with the line being perpendicular to the said diagonal.

Next I interpreted the minimal distance as this: I have two diagonals in the square, from which I can measure the distance. So I simply pick the one, who is lesser than the other.

With these assumptions, I get following image

[image]

where the blue area plus pink area (let's name it $A$) is the set of all points, for which $X < d$, where $d$ is chosen minimal distance. This area I calculated as follows:

Area of the "pink strip" can be stated as "the area of the triangle with red lining" minus "the are of the green triangle". That I calculated as $\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{16}(1-2\sqrt{2}d)^2$.

Next, the area $A$ is eight time the pink strip, so $A = 1 - \frac{1}{2}(1-2\sqrt{2}d)^2 $.

Now, since area of the unit square is one, than with usage of the geometric probability, the probability distribution is given as $P(X \leq d) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}(1-2\sqrt{2}d)^2$.

What I would like to know is whether I am correct or not? And if not, where did I make a mistake? Thanks for help.

Comment: Your reasoning is perfect, but I see one small error in your calculation: the area of the green triangle should be $\frac{1}{8}(1 - 2 \sqrt 2 d)^2$ instead of $\frac{1}{16}(1 - 2 \sqrt 2 d)^2$. When $d = 0$, your expression for the area of the pink strip should give zero!

Comment: I see, thanks for correction.